# Translating a Q_ENUM keys

Tags: qt, qmetaobject, qt-linguist

I use the `Q_ENUM` macro in my code, and then I use the associated `QMetaEnum` to populate a `QComboBox`.

Is there any "standard" way to manage the translation of the `Q_ENUM` keys (retrieved with `QMetaEnum::key()` method)?

I didn't find anything in the Qt's documentation, and the main problem is to automatically add translations keys in the *.ts files for all keys of the `Q_ENUM`.

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, thats not supported by Qt

Answer (score 2):

You do have to provide the translation keys yourself, with a series of `QT_TR_NOOP()` expansions, for `lupdate` to pick them up.

If that's really onerous, you could write a small program to generate a suitable input file for `lupdate` from your meta-object.